# Why am getting two ajax calls at same time?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make a like on article , am using onclick event on a `<div>` where another function handles the request, here are the codes :

```
<div class="act">
    <respect class="respect">
      {% if new.voted_new(new.id) %}
        <div class="button_like" data-new="{{new.id}}" onclick="Unlike();">
            <div class="norespect" style="background: #2fcc71; border-color: #2fcc71;"></div>
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="button_like" data-new="{{new.id}}"  onclick="Like();">
            <div class="norespect" style=""></div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
        <p class='respectCount{{new.id}}'>{{new.respects}}</p>
    </respect>
    <views>
      <p class="views_count"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> {{new.views}}</p>
    </views>
</div>
```

Here is `JQuery` code :

```
function Like(){
    $('.button_like, .respectCount').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var new_id = $(this).attr('data-new');
      var p_result = $(this).attr('data-result');
      $.ajax({
        url: "/client/cat-{{g.current_directory}}/news/like/",
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        data: {
          new_id: new_id
        },
        success: function(data){
          $('p.respectCount'+new_id).text(data.result);
          console.log(data.result);
          $(this).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        },
        error: function(data){
          return false;
        }
      }).done(function(data){
        if (data){
          $('p.respectCount'+new_id).text(data.result);
          console.log(data.result);
          $(this).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    });
});
}
```

The problem is that i have to click twice to make a like, also inside the console i got two ajax requests .

Please , any help ??

Comment: Probably u have called the data for two times once on success another on ajax completion.Please remove the function call on ajax completion

Comment: (not related to the issue) You have defined both `success:` and `done()` - both will be called.

Comment: No sir, i forgot to comment them out, am not acutally using them , sorry about that !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your HTML, you have added inline click handler

```
<div class="button_like" data-new="{{new.id}}"  onclick="Like();">
</div>
```

And in the event handler, you are attaching unobtrusive event handler. Thus whenever `button` is clicked a new handler is attached.

**Remove**, ugly inline click handlers and just use unobtrusive event handlers

```
$(function () {
    $('.button_like, .respectCount').on('click', function (e) {
        //Your code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside function `Like` should be outside, in its own `document.ready(function{...})`. `Like` should be sending its own ajax request.  Same probably for `Unlike`, which you haven't shown the code of.

Comment: Thanks for your interest dude , appreciated ;) .